# How to fix “Incorrect string value for the column at the row 1” errors?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, encryption

```
How to fix “Incorrect string value for the column at the row 1” errors
```

In my java project, I am using hibernate so in my entity class for the field PASSWORD.

I want to use encryption and decryption using the @ColumnTransformer

```
    @Column(name="PASSWORD",length=100)
    @ColumnTransformer(
              read="AES_DECRYPT(PASSWORD, 'ABCD')", 
              write="AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'ABCD')")
    private String password;
```

but at the saving time, it is throwing following exception

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Incorrect string value: '\x80\x11(\xC4\xAB\x10...' for column 'PASSWORD' at row 1
```

So How can I resolved above exception?

Comment: If you can try changing the data type to longtext.

Comment: I tried with longtext but still error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Is it MySQL database?

For mysql database, you may need to change Character set of column, in your case Password

you can do this using below SQL. Change **size** and **not null** options as per your need

```
ALTER TABLE database.table MODIFY COLUMN PASSWORD VARCHAR(100)  CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```